# RichTextBox space issue

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, rtf

I created an extended RichTextBox with better image displaying support. For short: I parse text-based image placeholders from the RTF-input, replace them by an empty paragraph with a propriate spacing (image height) and draw the images in the paint event above the text (inside the spaces).

The problem now is that the spacing seems to be wrong. I calculated the twips with the following formula:

```
size.Width = (int)((1440 * size.Width) / graphics.DpiX);
size.Height = (int)((1440 * size.Height) / graphics.DpiY);
```

Where `graphics` is from my `RichTextBox` and `size` is the image size. As the DPI value is 96, it is basically `twips = 15 * pixels`.

I tried the RTF control words `\sbN` and `\saN` with my calculated twips-value (I controlled it with the debugger, the value is as expected). I also used interop with `PFM_SPACEBEFORE` and `PFM_SPACEAFTER`.

Both ways give the same result. The problem is that the real space inside the RichTextBox is too big. If I multiply the calculated twips value with 0.75 it fits. But I really don't get why this happens.

My first thought was the factor 72 / 96 (PPI / DPI) which is 0.75. But this makes no sense for me.

The additional space increases proportional to the image height. So the space is barely noteable for small icons (e.g. 24 pixels height). But for larger images (e.g. 320 pixels height) the additional space is huge.

Some ideas? Is this a bug in the RichTextBox control?

To clarify: I used `System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox` as a base class.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the error by myself. I had to use the DPI values of the image instead of the DPI values of the control. The image DPI values were 120 so the factor was 0.8 (not 0.75). Now it fits. I leave the question here in case someone has the same problem.